# Many-To-Many relationship in cshtml not getting data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Trying to connected 2 models with Many-To-many relationship and display the data in cshtml using viewModel.
Model Book (data annotations removed for simplicity):

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public int PublisherId { get; set; }
public Publisher Publisher { get; set; }
public double Cost { get; set; }
public int Code { get; set; }
public int InvNr { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public IList<BookAuthor> BookAuthors { get; set; }
```

and Author model (data annotations removed for simplicity):

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Lastname { get; set; }
public IList<BookAuthor> BookAuthors { get; set; }
```

Since its a Many-To-Many relationship, created another model for these models BookAuthor (data annotations removed for simplicity):

```
public int BookId { get; set; }
public Book Book { get; set; }
public int AuthorId { get; set; }
public Author Author { get; set; }
```

Inside my DataAccess class i override ModelCreation (other tables removed for simplicity):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<BookAuthor>().HasKey(sc => new { sc.BookId, sc.AuthorId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<BookAuthor>().HasOne(sc => sc.Book)
            .WithMany(s => s.BookAuthors)
            .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.BookId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<BookAuthor>().HasOne(sc => sc.Author)
            .WithMany(s => s.BookAuthors)
            .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.AuthorId);
        }
    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BookAuthor> BookAuthors { get; set; }
```

Inserting the data from cshtml to database works fine.

**The Problem.**
Displaying the data returns a null value.
Inside the ViewModel (Other lines removed for simplicity) `public IEnumerable<Book> Books { get; set; }`, i give the Books variable data form my controller (Some lines removed for simplicity):

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult Index(int? Id)
{
    BooksIndexViewModel viewModel = new BooksIndexViewModel()
    {
        Books = _booksRepository.GetAllBooks(),
    };
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

The `_booksRepository.GetAllBooks()` returns : `return db.Books;`
db stand for my database `private readonly DataAccess db;`

Inside the cshtml.
I used foreach loop `foreach (var book in Model.Books)` for Model.Books. displaying the title, cost, code and so on, works fine. But the problem is With the Author. typing `book.BookAuthors` returns null value. 
If i understood correctly, `book.BookAuthors` should return a list therefor i tried using it inside the loop:

```
@foreach (var author in book.BookAuthors) { @author.Author.Name }
```

Tried `@foreach (var author in book.BookAuthors.Where(u => u.BookId == book.Id).Select(u => u.Author)) { @author.Name }` and few other similar attempts. The error ALWAYS occurs because of 
`book.BookAuthors` - its a null.

WHY?!

Shouldn't calling `book.BookAuthors` automatically connect from book to author tables using BookAuthors table as a bridge?

**IF** inside the controller i do this:

```
IEnumerable<Book> books = _booksRepository.GetAllBooks();
IEnumerable<BookAuthor> bookAuthors = _booksRepository.GetAllBookAuthors();
foreach (var book in books)
    foreach (var bookauth in bookAuthors)
    {
    }
```

(Yes the loop is empty) and pass it to my view model:

```
BooksIndexViewModel viewModel = new BooksIndexViewModel()
    {
        Books = books,
    };
```

Then this `@foreach (var author in book.BookAuthors) { @author.Author.Name}` inside of a loop `@foreach (var book in Model.Books)` inside the cshtml works fine...

WHY?! How come looping thru all available Books and BookAuthors inside the loop and not even assigning any values do the work?

Comment: I'ts null because you're not including related entities. You need to use `return db.Books.Include(x => x.BookAuthors)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data